# Printing a member of an array within a struct within a struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, fibonacci, memoization

Here I have a struct:

```
typedef struct Memo
{
// dynamically allocated HugeInteger array to store our Fibonacci numbers
    struct HugeInteger *F;

// the current length (i.e., capacity) of this array
    int length;

} Memo;
```

and this is the struct HugeInteger* within the Memo struct:

```
typedef struct HugeInteger
{
// a dynamically allocated array to hold the digits of a huge integer
    int *digits;

// the length of the array (i.e., number of digits in the huge integer)
    int length;
} HugeInteger;
```

My question is how can I access a member of the digits array within the Hugeinteger struct within the Memo struct?

I have malloced all three like so throughout my code:

```
Memo *newMemo = malloc(sizeof(Memo));

newMemo->F = malloc(sizeof(HugeInteger) * INIT_MEMO_SIZE); //in this case 44

    for (i = 0; i < INIT_MEMO_SIZE; i++)
    {
    newMemo->F[i].digits = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 1); //creating an array of size 1 to test
    newMemo->F[i].digits = NULL;
    newMemo->F[i].length = 0;
    }
```

I have tried for example...

```
newMemo->F[i].digits[0] = 1;
```

...which results in a segmentation fault. How can I implement the above line of code correctly? I really feel like i'm missing something important here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem right here:

```
newMemo->F[i].digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1); //creating an array of size 1 to test
newMemo->F[i].digits = NULL;
```

(Besides the syntax error that I fixed which I assume was a copy/paste error) The second line above replaces the memory address you just allocated with NULL. So that when you do this:

```
newMemo->F[i].digits[0] = 1;
```

You're writing to a NULL address.

You want to leave out the NULL assignment.

Comment: I tried what you asked and it is sitll segfaulting at newMemo->F[i].digits[0] = 1;

Comment: @mbratch Should be  `malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);`

Comment: Still segfaults on the same line unfortunately

Comment: @KarimElsheikh Time to fire up the debugger. We are not your debugger.

Comment: @Armin yes good catch (+1), I was just staring at that :) - I have changed it accordingly. Although, `sizeof(int*)` should be at least as large as `sizeof(int)` so it wouldn't be the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: @KarimElsheikh, it's unclear where your index `i` comes from in the example code you show for `newMemo->F[i].digits[0] = 1;` since it's not inside the loop you have.